# How to treat Custom Posts as normal posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Beginner here,
I created a Custom Post with https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
I then migrated all my posts to be the new custom post "skill".
However, I want my theme 'Sinatra' to treat the custom post as a normal post because right now in the hero banner, recent post widget, etc. the custom posts are not shown.
I tried inserting the following code into my functions.php but it did not work:

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type' );
/**
 * @param WP_Query $query
 * @return WP_Query
 */
function add_my_custom_post_type( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_main_query()) 
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'any_custom_type' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

I am also unsure where to put the code inside my functions.php. I tried to put it at the end of the functions.php but it did not work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the function in your functions.php, the important part is where it gets called, and this when the `pre_get_posts` gets triggered. Using `pre_get_posts` should work, unless there is some other restriction in your query that is filtering out the CPTs. Have you re-saved your permalinks to refresh them and confirmed the new CPT posts are working on the form end?